# manually exit from typing mode of textbox in WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a scenario in my windows phone 7 app. I have panarama control and it has 4 items in it. Let say in first Item I have textbox and my focus on it Mean My cursor in it and I was typing on this textbox. But when typing mean when my focus is still in textbox and I changes the panorama item. My textbox focus is still there and still its in typing mode. How I can exit my textbox from typing mode on panaroma selection change.

Comment: This is handy: http://pauliom.com/2010/09/04/keyboard-helper-class-for-wp7-vs-tab-index/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows Phone has no way to hide the keyboard other than to focus on a different element. 
For example, if you have a hidden button, call `button.focus();` to hide the soft-keyboard.